# VersionControlExt.Explorer is NULL if I call from solution explorer but if I call from Source Control Explorer then It is giving me value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am developing a plugin for viewing customized change set on button click in solution explorer.

I need VersionControlServer reference for that, but I am not getting the reference if I click button from Solution explorer, But If click the button from source control explorer then it is working. But I need to call it from solution explorer/ Team Explorer.

`this.m_applicationObject = _applicationObject;
            this.versionControlExt = (VersionControlExt)this.m_applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt");
            this.versionControlServer = this.versionControlExt.Explorer.Workspace.VersionControlServer;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead I used the url of the tfs server to get the version control explorer.

```
var projectCollectionUri = new Uri(TFS_COLLECTION);
                var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(projectCollectionUri, new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssCredentials());
                projectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
                this.versionControlServer = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

> VersionControlExt.Explorer is NULL if I call from solution explorer
>   but if I call from Source Control Explorer then It is giving me value

I am afraid that you cannot get what you want by using `VersionControlExt.Explorer`.

`VersionControlExt.Explorer` just works for `Source Control Explorer` rather than `Solution Explorer`.

See this from [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh715846(v%3Dvs.120)):

[image]

Comment: Is there any other way so that I can get Changeset details directly from solution explorer or team explorer ?